# SQL SERVER : Date Format DDMMYYYY

Tags: sql-server

String: "FileName-13012018.txt"

How to parse value [13012018] from column1[varchar] and insert into another column2[date] .

I can Parse using substring/ left/right function but i can't able to insert into column2[date].

My goal is to fetch this date from multiple rows and findout max of date.

Column1

---

FileName-13012018.txt

FileName-14012018.txt

FileName-15012018.txt

result : 15012018

Comment: Can you tell us the sql server version, so we may find the easiest solution? datefromparts() needs 2012

Comment: Will the date string always occupy the same positions with respect to the end of the string?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis its 2014

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it may differ, I now i have clue to parse the string, but comparing the parsed values and considering it as date and finding the max date is my problem

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is my parsing logic left(right(FileName,12),8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `datefromparts` creates a date from its parts.

Considering you have already parsed the "fileName" and "txt" out of the field result, try this:

```
select max(
            datefromparts(
                            right(result,4), --year
                            substring(result,3,2), --month
                            left(result,2) --day)
                        )
            )
from table_with_parsed_result
```

Answer (score 1):

Another posssible aproach is to remove unnecessery chars and generate valid date:

```
DECLARE @TmpTable TABLE (
    FFileName varchar(50)
)

INSERT @TmpTable
VALUES 
    ('FileName-13012018.txt'),
    ('FileName-14012018.txt'),
    ('FileName-15012018.txt')

SELECT 
    MAX(DATEFROMPARTS(
        SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(FFileName, 'Filename-', ''), '.txt', ''), 5, 4),
        SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(FFileName, 'Filename-', ''), '.txt', ''), 3, 2),
        SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(FFileName, 'Filename-', ''), '.txt', ''), 1, 2)
    )) AS FMaxDate
FROM @TmpTable
```